# After configuring Nexus 3 SSL Nexus no longer runs without sudo

Tags: nexus

I had my new Nexus 3 repository running okay.  I was able to configure some of the basic settings.  Then I went through the process of enabling SSL. I used the instructions [here](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/security.html#ssl-inbound).  I also watched the video on that page, which does not give instructions that match the page.

**My system info:** `ubuntu 14.4 with Java 8.`
Install directory: `/opt/nexus-3.0.0-b2016011501/`
To simplify the path, I created a link to this directory: `nexus -> /opt/nexus-3.0.0-b2016011501/` therefore the path to nexus is `/opt/nexus`

**I generated my keystore as follows:**
Created directory: `/opt/nexus/etc/ssl` 
Changed to that directory and ran: `keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 3650`. This generated a file called `keystore`. I then copied that file to `keystore.jks`.

**Updated the following files:**  `/opt/nexus/etc/org.sonatype.nexus.cfg` added `application-port-ssl=443` and added `${karaf.etc}/jetty-https.xml`(this is different from the written instructions) to the end of the `nexus-args=$` line. Then (this is in the video, but not the written instructions) I edited the /opt/nexus/etc/jetty-https.xml file and replaced the password in three places with the password I specified when I generated my keystore.

After this if I start nexus with `./nexus run` it get the following error:

```
2016-01-27 02:20:41,013+0000 ERROR [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Failed to start
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.5.v20151012]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:274) [org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap:3.0.0.b2016011501]
```

If it start it with `sudo ./nexus run` it will work but shows me the nag message saying I should not run it as root.

I have verified that my user is the owner of all the files and directories /opt/nexus

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (and other unix type systems) you can't run on port numbers less than 1024 unless you are root.   The best way to solve this is to run Nexus behind a reverse proxy.  You can find instructions for this here:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html

The above was written for Nexus 2.x, but the configuration needed will be the same in Nexus 3.

Regarding running as non-root as a service, there is a bug in 3.0m7 that makes this problematic:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9437

The fix is to edit the "bin/nexus" startup script is to replace this line:

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX="su - $run_as_user -c"
```

With this:

```
exec su - $run_as_user "$prg_dir/$progname" $@
```

This fix will be in the next release.

Once that change is made, symlink $NEXUS_HOME/bin/nexus to /etc/init.d/nexus, then install the service. And edit "$NEXUS_HOME/bin/nexus.rc" and set the "run_as_user" appropriately.

Comment: I did as recommended. Ran `sudo update-rc.d nexus defaults` but when I attempt to start the service this is what happens:  >`service nexus start`
>`No passwd entry for user '/'`